# Using additive or multiplicative notation when showing isomorphism (between a subgroup and its left coset)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

I'm trying to understand the proof of that all left cosets of a group $G$ with respect to a subgroup $H$ are equivalent.
http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cosets_are_Equivalent

And I'm stuck on a tiny detail.

I have my mapping 
$\theta: H \to Hx$ with $\theta(u) = ux$

And the proof claims that $H \simeq Hx$ and I'm totally ok with the identity mapping and the bijection. But how about the property $\theta(u * v) = \theta(u) \# \theta(u)$?

I think I'm confused with what kind of notation I should use. If just assume it's additive then it works out fine since $\theta(u+v) = (u+v)x = ux + vx = \theta(u) + \theta(v)$. But can I really assume this? After all $H$ is a subgroup of any group. Is there a convention how one should think about this when working with groups in general?

Another question on the same topic. In this very case $\theta(u * v) = \theta(u) \# \theta(u)$ then $*$ and $\#$ are the same binary operator, right?

Comment: $\theta$ is not a homomomorphism! In fact $Hx$ is not a group unless $x\in H$ (since $e \notin Hx$). $\theta$ is merely a bijection. Nothing more.

Comment: So the proof is false or am I misinterpreting "..This establishes H≃Hx"?

Comment: I believe $\simeq$ here denotes bijection, not isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here symbol $\simeq$ means just a bijection between two sets, since in general $Hx$ is not a group. For the second question, it is not true that if $\theta(u*v) = \theta(u)\#\theta(u) $ then $*$ and $\#$ are the same binary operator. Just compare two sides: $\theta(u*v)=uvx$, and r.h.s. is $uxvx$. Also, you can't write $\theta(u+v) = (u+v)x = ux + vx = \theta(u) + \theta(v)$, because $H$ has only one operation, not both multiplication and addition.